# Vulkan demo does not compile on Nvidia Jetson TX2

Tags: vulkan

I have downloaded the Vulkan SDK from LunarG here:

https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools/

I have compiled it successfully using the instructions in BUILDvt.md and have a "vulkan" directory which has the vulkan.h and vulkan.hpp files. I have copied this entire vulkan directory tino /usr/local/include so that gcc can find it.

However when I go to the demos directory in my VulkanTools and type gcc cube.h I get this:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/code/VulkanTools/demos$ gcc cube.c
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `vec3_len':
cube.c:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `sqrtf'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `mat4x4_rotate':
cube.c:(.text+0xa38): undefined reference to `sinf'
cube.c:(.text+0xa44): undefined reference to `cosf'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `mat4x4_perspective':
cube.c:(.text+0xbe4): undefined reference to `tan'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_flush_init_cmd':
cube.c:(.text+0x15ac): undefined reference to `vkEndCommandBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x160c): undefined reference to `vkCreateFence'
cube.c:(.text+0x169c): undefined reference to `vkQueueSubmit'
cube.c:(.text+0x16f0): undefined reference to `vkWaitForFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x174c): undefined reference to `vkFreeCommandBuffers'
cube.c:(.text+0x1760): undefined reference to `vkDestroyFence'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_set_image_layout':
cube.c:(.text+0x1940): undefined reference to `vkCmdPipelineBarrier'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_draw_build_cmd':
cube.c:(.text+0x1a78): undefined reference to `vkBeginCommandBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x1ac0): undefined reference to `vkCmdBeginRenderPass'
cube.c:(.text+0x1ad8): undefined reference to `vkCmdBindPipeline'
cube.c:(.text+0x1b30): undefined reference to `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets'
cube.c:(.text+0x1b84): undefined reference to `vkCmdSetViewport'
cube.c:(.text+0x1bcc): undefined reference to `vkCmdSetScissor'
cube.c:(.text+0x1be4): undefined reference to `vkCmdDraw'
cube.c:(.text+0x1bec): undefined reference to `vkCmdEndRenderPass'
cube.c:(.text+0x1cc8): undefined reference to `vkCmdPipelineBarrier'
cube.c:(.text+0x1cd0): undefined reference to `vkEndCommandBuffer'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_build_image_ownership_cmd':
cube.c:(.text+0x1dac): undefined reference to `vkBeginCommandBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x1ec8): undefined reference to `vkCmdPipelineBarrier'
cube.c:(.text+0x1ef0): undefined reference to `vkEndCommandBuffer'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_update_data_buffer':
cube.c:(.text+0x204c): undefined reference to `vkWaitForFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x20a0): undefined reference to `vkMapMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x2124): undefined reference to `vkUnmapMemory'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_draw':
cube.c:(.text+0x2778): undefined reference to `vkWaitForFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x27b0): undefined reference to `vkResetFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x29cc): undefined reference to `vkResetFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x2a18): undefined reference to `vkQueueSubmit'
cube.c:(.text+0x2b0c): undefined reference to `vkQueueSubmit'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_buffers':
cube.c:(.text+0x3388): undefined reference to `vkWaitForFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x364c): undefined reference to `vkCreateImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x36c4): undefined reference to `vkCreateFence'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_depth':
cube.c:(.text+0x391c): undefined reference to `vkCreateImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x3974): undefined reference to `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements'
cube.c:(.text+0x3a44): undefined reference to `vkAllocateMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x3aa0): undefined reference to `vkBindImageMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x3b08): undefined reference to `vkCreateImageView'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_texture_image':
cube.c:(.text+0x3efc): undefined reference to `vkCreateImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x3f54): undefined reference to `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements'
cube.c:(.text+0x3ff4): undefined reference to `vkAllocateMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x4050): undefined reference to `vkBindImageMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x40d0): undefined reference to `vkGetImageSubresourceLayout'
cube.c:(.text+0x4104): undefined reference to `vkMapMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x41b4): undefined reference to `vkUnmapMemory'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_destroy_texture_image':
cube.c:(.text+0x421c): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x423c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImage'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_textures':
cube.c:(.text+0x4288): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x4550): undefined reference to `vkCmdCopyImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x46e0): undefined reference to `vkCreateSampler'
cube.c:(.text+0x477c): undefined reference to `vkCreateImageView'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_cube_data_buffers':
cube.c:(.text+0x4a68): undefined reference to `vkCreateBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x4adc): undefined reference to `vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements'
cube.c:(.text+0x4b88): undefined reference to `vkAllocateMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x4c08): undefined reference to `vkMapMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x4c94): undefined reference to `vkUnmapMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x4cf8): undefined reference to `vkBindBufferMemory'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_descriptor_layout':
cube.c:(.text+0x4e10): undefined reference to `vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout'
cube.c:(.text+0x4ea0): undefined reference to `vkCreatePipelineLayout'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_render_pass':
cube.c:(.text+0x5058): undefined reference to `vkCreateRenderPass'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_shader_module':
cube.c:(.text+0x511c): undefined reference to `vkCreateShaderModule'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_pipeline':
cube.c:(.text+0x56b0): undefined reference to `vkCreatePipelineCache'
cube.c:(.text+0x5778): undefined reference to `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines'
cube.c:(.text+0x57cc): undefined reference to `vkDestroyShaderModule'
cube.c:(.text+0x57ec): undefined reference to `vkDestroyShaderModule'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_descriptor_pool':
cube.c:(.text+0x58bc): undefined reference to `vkCreateDescriptorPool'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_descriptor_set':
cube.c:(.text+0x5b00): undefined reference to `vkAllocateDescriptorSets'
cube.c:(.text+0x5bcc): undefined reference to `vkUpdateDescriptorSets'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare_framebuffers':
cube.c:(.text+0x5d1c): undefined reference to `vkCreateFramebuffer'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_prepare':
cube.c:(.text+0x5e00): undefined reference to `vkCreateCommandPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x5e7c): undefined reference to `vkAllocateCommandBuffers'
cube.c:(.text+0x5ed4): undefined reference to `vkBeginCommandBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x5f88): undefined reference to `vkAllocateCommandBuffers'
cube.c:(.text+0x6030): undefined reference to `vkCreateCommandPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x60d0): undefined reference to `vkAllocateCommandBuffers'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_cleanup':
cube.c:(.text+0x623c): undefined reference to `vkDeviceWaitIdle'
cube.c:(.text+0x627c): undefined reference to `vkWaitForFences'
cube.c:(.text+0x62ac): undefined reference to `vkDestroyFence'
cube.c:(.text+0x62d4): undefined reference to `vkDestroySemaphore'
cube.c:(.text+0x62fc): undefined reference to `vkDestroySemaphore'
cube.c:(.text+0x6334): undefined reference to `vkDestroySemaphore'
cube.c:(.text+0x6390): undefined reference to `vkDestroyFramebuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x63d0): undefined reference to `vkDestroyDescriptorPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x63f0): undefined reference to `vkDestroyPipeline'
cube.c:(.text+0x6410): undefined reference to `vkDestroyPipelineCache'
cube.c:(.text+0x6430): undefined reference to `vkDestroyRenderPass'
cube.c:(.text+0x6450): undefined reference to `vkDestroyPipelineLayout'
cube.c:(.text+0x6470): undefined reference to `vkDestroyDescriptorSetLayout'
cube.c:(.text+0x64b4): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x64f0): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x652c): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x6568): undefined reference to `vkDestroySampler'
cube.c:(.text+0x65c8): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x65e8): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x6608): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x664c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x6694): undefined reference to `vkFreeCommandBuffers'
cube.c:(.text+0x66d0): undefined reference to `vkDestroyBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x670c): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x6748): undefined reference to `vkDestroyFence'
cube.c:(.text+0x67a0): undefined reference to `vkDestroyCommandPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x67d0): undefined reference to `vkDestroyCommandPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x67dc): undefined reference to `vkDeviceWaitIdle'
cube.c:(.text+0x67ec): undefined reference to `vkDestroyDevice'
cube.c:(.text+0x6844): undefined reference to `vkDestroySurfaceKHR'
cube.c:(.text+0x6854): undefined reference to `vkDestroyInstance'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_resize':
cube.c:(.text+0x6898): undefined reference to `vkDeviceWaitIdle'
cube.c:(.text+0x68dc): undefined reference to `vkDestroyFramebuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x691c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyDescriptorPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x693c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyPipeline'
cube.c:(.text+0x695c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyPipelineCache'
cube.c:(.text+0x697c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyRenderPass'
cube.c:(.text+0x699c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyPipelineLayout'
cube.c:(.text+0x69bc): undefined reference to `vkDestroyDescriptorSetLayout'
cube.c:(.text+0x6a00): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x6a3c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x6a78): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x6ab4): undefined reference to `vkDestroySampler'
cube.c:(.text+0x6aec): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x6b0c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImage'
cube.c:(.text+0x6b2c): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x6b70): undefined reference to `vkDestroyImageView'
cube.c:(.text+0x6bb8): undefined reference to `vkFreeCommandBuffers'
cube.c:(.text+0x6bf4): undefined reference to `vkDestroyBuffer'
cube.c:(.text+0x6c30): undefined reference to `vkFreeMemory'
cube.c:(.text+0x6c6c): undefined reference to `vkDestroyFence'
cube.c:(.text+0x6cac): undefined reference to `vkDestroyCommandPool'
cube.c:(.text+0x6cdc): undefined reference to `vkDestroyCommandPool'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_init_vk':
cube.c:(.text+0x6ea4): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x6f18): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x7084): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x70f8): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x73d0): undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance'
cube.c:(.text+0x7478): undefined reference to `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices'
cube.c:(.text+0x74ec): undefined reference to `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices'
cube.c:(.text+0x7578): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x761c): undefined reference to `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x7998): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x79c0): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x7a50): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x7b94): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x7bb4): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x7c38): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties'
cube.c:(.text+0x7c48): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures'
cube.c:(.text+0x7c64): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x7cc0): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x7d1c): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x7d78): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x7dd4): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_create_device':
cube.c:(.text+0x7f54): undefined reference to `vkCreateDevice'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_init_vk_swapchain':
cube.c:(.text+0x823c): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x82e4): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x838c): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x8434): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
cube.c:(.text+0x84dc): undefined reference to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr'
/tmp/ccbouT30.o:cube.c:(.text+0x8594): more undefined references to `vkGetInstanceProcAddr' follow
/tmp/ccbouT30.o: In function `demo_init_vk_swapchain':
cube.c:(.text+0x86dc): undefined reference to `vkGetDeviceQueue'
cube.c:(.text+0x8730): undefined reference to `vkGetDeviceQueue'
cube.c:(.text+0x8908): undefined reference to `vkCreateFence'
cube.c:(.text+0x8970): undefined reference to `vkCreateSemaphore'
cube.c:(.text+0x89d8): undefined reference to `vkCreateSemaphore'
cube.c:(.text+0x8a50): undefined reference to `vkCreateSemaphore'
cube.c:(.text+0x8ac0): undefined reference to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/code/VulkanTools/demos$
```

Is this a driver problem? Or is my compiler or include file setup wrong?

Comment: You probably didn't install the libraries. You need to also link with the loader.

Comment: @tambre: where will I find the libraries? Can you give me a hint or two on what they look like? Apols very new to this. Do you mean the Vulkan driver?

Comment: You don't link with the driver (lol) - the Vulkan loader loads the appropriate addresses for the functions in the driver when you call Vulkan functions. On Windows the Vulkan loader is `vulkan-1.lib`. Considering that you built from source, it was probably also built somewhere - I don't know the details as `apt install libvulkan-dev` and the Vulkan SDK have been good enough for me.

Comment: Actually I think I found it in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvulkan

Comment: `libvulkan.so` on Linux (which is linked to `libvulkan.so.1`, which would be linked further to more specific version). It should be compiled as part of VulkanTools (and so somewhere in its tree). If you found it installed on the system, you should perhaps uninstall `libvulkan-dev` and `libvulkan1`packages, and use your compiled stuff instead.

Comment: @krOoze aha! Yes I have found libvulkan.so which seems to symlink to libvulkan.so.1 which itself symlinks to what appears to be a newer libvulkan.so.1.0.48 (the installed one was libvulkan.so.1.0.21). But now these are all sitting in ~/code/VulkanTools/dbuild/loader whereas the "installed" libvulkans (.so, .1.so, and .1.0.21) are all in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu). How do I get the entire VulkanTools that I have built to be used by default instead of the pre-installed one? Is there a compiler directive? Can I move the entire VulkanTools directory somewhere?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Uninstall `libvulkan1` and `libvulkan-dev`. Then copy your version of headers into `include/vulkan/` and your compiled libs where the system ones were(ideally following similar scheme using `ln -sf`, but just having `libvulkan.so` should be fine too). There's no trick here. The point is only that the `*.so` is in `PATH` so the app can see it and so you don't have to state `-Lpath` while compiling. EDIT: Actually, gonna make some kind of Answer for formality sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issues when trying to compile https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan for NVIDIA Jetson TX2.

I was able to get around this by creating a symlink from  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ to the projects libvulkan.so

basically:

```
$ cd <PATH_TO_LIBVULKAN_IN_PROJECT>
$ ln -s /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1 libvulkan.so
```

If you then do an "ls -lt" in the directory you should see something like this:

```
$ ls -lt
libvulkan.so -> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not compile with `-lvulkan`, so the definitions of listed Vulkan commands are missing. It is simple as that.

On typical Linux distro you need the `libvulkan1` (has `libvulkan.so` and frends) and the `libvulkan-dev` package (has `vulkan.h`). For development you would need other things like the Validation Layers and `glslangValidator` (not sure they are packaged). The packages might not exist, or be too outdated for your taste on your distro.

Another choice would be the [LunarG SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home). It would have all the stuff in one place and is updated often. But does not automatically install into system locations/`PATH`. Also it is only provided (at the time of writing) for x86_64.

Last choice is to compile yourself (as you did). As the SDK it does not automatically install into system locations/`PATH`. So that need to be dealt with and also making sure you are not using accidentaly preinstalled versions in `libvulkan1` and `libvulkan-dev`.

Comment: You also need `-lm` to get `sqrtf`, `sinf`, etc. which are also missing.

Comment: Yes I'm running aarch64 (Nvidia Jetson TX2) hence the compile. The major issue seems to be that the VulkanTools directory tree is f* enormous, and there is no rpm or dpkg that is created to stick all the right things into the right place. Trial and error based on your advice above I guess. Starting with VulkanTools/include and build/install/bin which seems to contain glslangValidator that you mention. There are literally 462 directories under VulkanTools and I can't put them all in the path. Vulkan sure doesn't waste any time banging you into its learning curve ;-)